Naa Mei Bhakta Pranshyati - Conditions where it applies
In Slokam 9.31 BG, Krishna says

BHAGAVAD GITA CHAPTER 9 VERSE 31
Bg. 9.31 क्षिप्रं भवति धर्मात्मा शश्वच्छान्तिं निगच्छति । कौन्तेय
प्रतिजानीहि न मे भक्त: प्रणश्यति ॥ ३१ ॥
He quickly becomes righteous and attains lasting peace. O son of
Kuntī, declare it boldly that My devotee never perishes.

Does it apply only on highly devotional devotees who always think of god and extremely devoted who have done lot of sadhana ?
Because in BG 9.22 Krishna says अनन्याश्चिन्तयन्तो मां ये जना: पर्युपासते (Those who always think of Me and engage in
exclusive devotion to Me)

BHAGAVAD GITA: CHAPTER 9, Verse 22
अनन्याश्चिन्तयन्तो मां ये जना: पर्युपासते | तेषां नित्याभियुक्तानां योगक्षेमं वहाम्यहम् || 22||
"BG 9.22: There are those who always think of Me and engage in
exclusive devotion to Me. To them, whose minds are always absorbed in
Me, I provide what they lack and preserve what they already possess."

So does the assurance or promise krishna gives in BG 9.31 न मे भक्त: प्रणश्यति only apply for those ananya bhakta as mentioned in BG 9.22 or does it apply for all devotees who are doing bhakti even if they are not advanced to that stage where they always think of god but intermediate level those who do worship Puja chanting etc ?

Hello, there is a Gita verse in which Lord Krishna, after hearing Arjuna wonder whether a yogi can perish like a separated cloud, says a yogi does not fall from the right path but gets another opportunity to continue his sadhana.

That is different. That comes in BG Chapter 6

Yeah I know, but it answers your question "Does it apply to all devotees...even if they are not advanced." The chapter six verse then implies that Lord Krishna "provides what they lack and preserves what they already possess" by ensuring such intermediate level yogis do not fall (i.e. preserve that they have) and go to appropriate places to enhance their sadhana (i.e. provide what they lack). So the chapter 6 verse answers your question regarding the chapter 9 verse since the Bhagavat Gita provides a unified message through diverse means.

No sir . Actually in BG 6.41 and BG 9 22 It's for Yogis. Yogis who always meditate and think of god for them both of them apply. Yogi means highest stage of sadhana . It doesn't apply for intermediate actually. And my Pandit said Yoga marga and Bhakti marga are different. My question is in BG 9.31 krishna doesn't mention any condition he just says his devotees doesn't perish. So my question is this particular sloka 9.31 is applying for all devotees even if they are intermediate or it only applies to advanced devotees (as mentioned in 9.22)

Bg 9.31 applies for all lord is kartum akartun anyatha kartum he can do anything no need to be doubtful and if you pray to lord and as a pryaschitta do naam japa and say to lord (Radha Krishna or only  Shri Radha) that I am under your shelter and I am yours no matter how many promises I break or papa karmas I do I still am yours and I have taken your shelter then as per sanat kumar samhita and padma purana you will definately attain God and if you are still worried about promises them refer bg 18.66 and after doing all this do naam japa and transfer it to your parents(by praying to lord)
